# G1GC Strange behavior

Tags: java, garbage-collection, g1gc

I've decided to try G1GC on my Eclipse Mars RC3 for JavaEE developers  installation, but I observed a very strange behavior:

[image: GCViewer statistics]

As you can see it has run almost 700 FULL GCs for the lifecycle of the application, while only 30 minor GCs. Also I noticed that that the minor GCs are executed when the application is under load - usually when it starts and loads a lot of stuff, while it does full GCs when it's idle. (It was idle most of these 11 hours!) I would expect that when the application does nothing there would be no need for GC, or at leas it would be a minor GC. I also monitored the memory consumption of eclipse - during idle time it never incresed to more that 130-140 MB, so this is one more reason why these full GCs look strange.

Here is my eclipse.ini jvm config:

```
-server
-Xverify:none
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
-Xloggc:/home/svetlin/software/eclipse/gc.log
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps 
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5
-XX:GCLogFileSize=20m
-Xms1g
-Xmx1g
```

Here is the GC log: http://pastebin.com/sVBe4w1A

Java version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_45-internal-b14), built on May 17 2015 19:21:01 by "buildd" with gcc 4.9.2

Do you have any idea why G1GC does these full GC when there is obviously not need for GC at all ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are suffering from `System.gc()` calls as can be seen in your log:

```
2015-06-14T14:56:23.682+0300: 12790,173: [Full GC (System.gc())  121M->118M(1024M), 0,4524898 secs]
   [Eden: 4096,0K(561,0M)->0,0B(561,0M) Survivors: 0,0B->0,0B Heap: 121,7M(1024,0M)->118,2M(1024,0M)], [Metaspace: 135216K->135216K(1177600K)]
 [Times: user=0,71 sys=0,00, real=0,45 secs]
2015-06-14T14:57:23.682+0300: 12850,174: [Full GC (System.gc())  121M->118M(1024M), 0,4732930 secs]
   [Eden: 3072,0K(561,0M)->0,0B(561,0M) Survivors: 0,0B->0,0B Heap: 121,2M(1024,0M)->118,2M(1024,0M)], [Metaspace: 135216K->135216K(1177600K)]
 [Times: user=0,73 sys=0,00, real=0,47 secs]
2015-06-14T14:58:28.684+0300: 12915,175: [Full GC (System.gc())  169M->118M(1024M), 0,4912699 secs]
   [Eden: 52,0M(561,0M)->0,0B(561,0M) Survivors: 0,0B->0,0B Heap: 169,9M(1024,0M)->118,8M(1024,0M)], [Metaspace: 135601K->135601K(1177600K)]
 [Times: user=0,74 sys=0,00, real=0,49 secs]
```

The `System.gc()` calls seem to happen once every minute. Do you run any weird plugins that could cause this?

Otherwise, periodic `System.gc()` calls are often due to the Java RMI runtime calling them. On older Java versions I think this was done every minute but is now increased to once every hour. Regardless, try setting those properties just to be sure:

```
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=999999999
-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=999999999
```

as JVM options.

Comment: Lol, I should have look manually in to the logs instead of using the GCViewer. It's interesting though which component is calling System.gc() and why.

Answer (score 2):

All your full GCs are caused by calls to `System.gc()`. Your GC log shows exactly 698 of them.

So your Eclipse distro might contain a plugin that causes this number of `System.gc()` calls. If you cannot fix these calls you might consider using the VM option `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC` to suppress explicit GCs.